# Hide notification if data attribute value is 0 or empty

Tags: javascript, html, css, custom-data-attribute

I have this code that will display notification circle:

### HTML:

```
      <div class="icon-container">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt">
            <span onclick="showDetails(this)" id="MyControl" data-counter="2"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
```

### CSS

```
[data-counter]:after {
    content: attr(data-counter);
    position: absolute;
    top:-3px;
    right: -14px;
    padding: 3px 9px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius:100px;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #FF6969 0%,#ff0000 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FF6969 0%,#ff0000 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FF6969 0%,#ff0000 100%);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5), 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.4), 0 0 1px     rgba(0,0,0,.7) inset, 0 10px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.11) inset; 
    background-clip: padding-box;
    font:bold 12px/18px "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif; 
    color: white;
    text-decoration: no;
    z-index: 1;
    }
```

### Output

[image]

My question is how do I hide the notification circle if `data-counter="0"` or `data-counter=""`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[data-counter="0"]:after,
[data-counter=""]:after {
    display: none;
}
```

I guess this would do the trick?

Comment: I have been trying to solve this for many hours. Thank you very much.